# How to run my code on files from different folders?

Tags: python

```
a=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/D/Desktop/Files500/1/FIELD-3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TOp']['data'])

#iterations

a=a.flatten(order='C')
iter_num = 10; i=iter_num
while i < x:
    a = np.insert(a, i, (a[i]+a[i-1])/2)
    i += iter_num

np.savetxt('merged.csv',a.flatten(order='C'),delimiter=',')
```

I have 500 folders and have a file with the same name in each of them, I would like to run them through my code and save it in the same csv with a delimiter ','. Is this possible? the folders names are 1,2...500.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate number 1..500 and replace the folder number in the path for both .h5 and .csv files

```
for i in range(1, 501):
    a=np.array(h5py.File(f'/Users/D/Desktop/Files500/{i}/FIELD-3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TOp']['data'])
    #iterations
    a=a.flatten(order='C')
    iter_num = 10; i=iter_num
    while i < x:
        a = np.insert(a, i, (a[i]+a[i-1])/2)
        i += iter_num

    np.savetxt(f'/Users/D/Desktop/Files500/{i}/merged.csv',a.flatten(order='C'),delimiter=',')
```